# color switch after the 2nd button click

Tags: android

how can i use the "switch statement" to switch the colors from button 1 to button 2, after the 2nd click?
these are my 2 button clicks

```
private int lCount = 0;
private int rCount = 0;
private int myCount = lCount & rCount;

final TextView countTextViewPlusL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL);
final Button countButtonPlusL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCountPlusL);

countButtonPlusL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        myCount++;
          if(myCount%2 == 0){
             countTextViewPlusL.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);}
          else countTextViewPlusL.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        lCount++;
        if (lCount >-1)
        countTextViewPlusL.setText("" + lCount);
    }
});


final TextView countTextViewPlusR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountR);
final Button countButtonPlusR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCountPlusR);

countButtonPlusR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        myCount++;
          if(myCount%2 == 0){
            countTextViewPlusR.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);}
          else countTextViewPlusR.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        rCount++;
        if (rCount >-1)
        countTextViewPlusR.setText("" + rCount);
    }
});
```

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator. Are you trying to add lCount and rCount? You should use `lCount + rCount` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing `lCount` and/or `rCount` in your listeners, but you are testing `myCount` for parity. That's why things don't change.

Comment: this is the private int:

    `private int lCount = 0; private int rCount = 0;  private int myCount = lCount & rCount;`

**how to use the switch statement**

Comment: Defining `mycount = lCount & rCount` sets `myCount` to a value that **does not change** simply because `lCount` and/or `rCount` changes. I suggest you write a function `int myCount() { return lCount & rCount; }` and use that instead. Or else just test against `((lCount & rCount) % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: ok but now i want to use a switch statement. how do i do that?

Comment: Why is using a switch statement necessary? Your parity test seems fine. If you need to change, then something like this will work: `switch (myCount()) { case 0: /* stuff */; break; case 1: /* etc */; break; }`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this instead?

```
private int lCount = 0;
private int rCount = 0;
private int myCount = 0;

final TextView countTextViewPlusL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL); 
final Button countButtonPlusL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCountPlusL);
final TextView countTextViewPlusR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountR); 
final Button countButtonPlusR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCountPlusR);

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ButtonCountPlusR:
                rCount++;
                break;
            case R.id.ButtonCountPlusL:
                lCount++;
                break;
        }
        myCount = lCount + rCount;
        if(myCount % 2 == 0) {
            //invert colors here
        }
    }
});

countButtonPlusL.setOnClickListener(listener);
countButtonPlusR.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Initialize all counters to zero, then check on each click which button was clicked, increment its counter, set myCount equal to the sum of both left and right counters, then check if it's a second click. Inside that check, invert your TextView colors.

Comment: i get an error on the last row.

";" `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`

.
and i get an error on the last "}" `Syntax error on token "}", { expected`

Comment: I just left off some parentheses and semicolons. Try it now.

Comment: what exactly do i have to fil in here: //invert colors here.
and how

Comment: Depends on how you're setting the colors, really. If you're just going to swap between black and white like you're showing there, there's not a `getBackgroundColor()` method, but I suppose you could use `getDrawable()` and get one pixel of it. XOR that color value with 1s and it should invert it. I don't have code offhand for that. Otherwise you could subclass your TextViews and have a variable to keep track of what the color was, and swap them that way.